# MySQL view with three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve this problem. I want to create a view with following data.

I have three tables:

```
Wares(id, recipe_name_id, input_date, input_quantity)
Recipe_names(id, name)
Wares_output(id, recipe_name_id, output_date, output_quantity)
```

I'm trying to get data to look like this:

```
recipe_name, input_date, input_quantity, output_date, output_quantity.
```

Where input or output quantity is null, row still appears for that date.

Example:

```
rubber - 10 - 2015.05.05 - NULL - NULL
gums   - NULL - NULL - 15 - 2015.05.06
pencil - 13 - 2015.05.07 - 11 - 2015.05.07
```

Comment: if you want replace null by some date, you can use ifnull() function

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like this

```
SELECT r.name AS recipe_name, w.input_date, w.input_quantity, o.output_date, o.output_quantity
FROM
    recipe_names r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wares w ON r.id=w.recipe_name_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wares_output o ON r.id=o.recipe_name_id
```